# render JSON array in HTTP node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, highland.js

I have a JSON string that I get from an express GET request which queries a mongo db.

`res.write(string)` gives me:

```
[
 {
  "_id":{
     "epc":"30742503C40AE4AE128918B1",
     "audit":109
  },
  "ss":{
     "x":1674,
     "y":96,
     "ts":"2016-05-09T02:24:03.000Z",
     "regions":[
        419,
        416,
        415,
        401
     ]
  },
  "v3":{
     "ts":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "sts":"2016-05-09T16:10:16.549Z",
     "location":"A002R028S03100100"
  }
 }
]
```

However, I want to only render certain information from the string, for example: **epc**, **audit**, **ss.ts**, **v3.ts** and **v3.location**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) and filter by the desired fields.

```
res.json({ ss: string.ss.ts });
res.json({ v3: string.v3.ts });
// ... etc
```

Or you can use `res.write` and filter the results:

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(
    string.map(function (result){ 
         return {ss: result.ss.ts}; 
    })
));
```

Comment: Thanks, Simo. Your answer really helped. I found that: res.write(JSON.stringify({ epc: d._id.epc, audit: d._id.audit, upc: d.gtin, desc: d.item.desc, ss: d.ss.regions, v3: d.v3.location }) + '\n') was what I needed.